How to avoid clangd inserting function argument placeholders for `std::endl`
I'm new to neovim and I want to set it up for a c++ project. I'm using kickstart.nvim and have enabled clangd and added cpp to treesitter.
I'm having an issue where the LSP suggestion for std::endl is not clever enough to see that I have already imported <iostream> and that I'm using operator<< on the stream so it should just select the symbol and not autocomplete to a function call.

How can I fix this to just autocomplete to std::endl when the option is selected?

Unrelated: Are you sure you want to? std::endl is both a newline and a flush of the stream buffer to the underlying media, and that flush can be surprisingly expensive. Generally best to leave the data in the stream buffer until it needs to be flushed. For best performance typically all you need to do is end the string with a \n.

Plus I don't see how the Liskov Substitution Principle (LSP) got involved.

@user4581301 Language Server Protocol

Clangd has this silly habit of inserting placeholders for function arguments. --function-arg-placeholders=false stops it.

std::endl is in fact a function, and can be used in this way:
std::endl(std::cout);

To implement the more common usage pattern:
std::cout << std::endl;

the standard library overloads operator<< for std::endl's function type.
From the point of view of editor tooling like clangd, std::endl is no different than any other function, and clangd behaviours associated with functions (such as inserting parentheses and argument placeholders when accepting a code completion proposal) will apply to std::endl as well.
Clangd does have an option to disable insertion of argument placeholders (for all functions, not just std::endl): the command-line argument --function-arg-placeholders=false. Note that parentheses will still be inserted; https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/63565 is on file about adding a more flexible option for governing this.
There is also https://github.com/clangd/clangd/issues/439 on file about changing behaviour for std::endl specifically.

Thank you for taking the time to answer this. Good to see its not just me that finds this a bit annoying. I'll follow the issues over at github.
